# Remove members of one variable from another in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to remove members of one variable from another and then assign the value to a new variable as follows:

```
$originalGroupMembers = Get-ADuser -Filter * | select name
$removeGroupMembers = Get-ADUser -Identity jbloggs | select  name
$updatedGroupMembers = $originalGroupMembers | Where-Object {$removeGroupMembers -NotContains $_}
```

I'm not having much luck. `$updatedGroupMembers` includes `jbloggs` which I'm trying to exclude.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out an easier way to do this.  Basically, you want to subtract values of one variable from another.  To do this, use compare-object

```
$originalGroupMembers = Get-ADuser -Filter * | Select-Object -Property 'name'

$removeGroupMembers = Get-ADUser -Identity 'jbloggs' | Select-Object -Property 'name'

$updatedGroupMembers = (compare-object -ReferenceObject $originalGroupMembers -DifferenceObject $removeGroupMembers).inputObject | sort-object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `jbloggs` by using `-Filter`

```
$updated_group_members = Get-ADuser -Filter {SamAccountName -ne 'jbloggs'}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to simply my problem but perhaps that didn't help. What i'm actually trying to do is remove an entire group of users that exist in a variable so $removeGroupMembers=Get-ADGroupMember -Identity grUserExclusionGroup | select name

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison is incorrect.

```
$originalGroupMembers = Get-ADuser -Filter * | Select-Object -Property 'name'
$removeGroupMembers = Get-ADUser -Identity 'jbloggs' | Select-Object -Property 'name'
$updatedGroupMembers = $originalGroupMembers | Where-Object { $removeGroupMembers.Name -NotContains $_.Name }
```

P.S. Specifying tags `v2` and `v3` is very misleading as `v3` introduced **quite** a few features.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: @Evan01 Great. Kindly mark this as the answer for future searchers then